# why is git finding directories that don't exist in my home directory?

Tags: git, directory, gitignore, ignore

I am running a git repository on Windows 10 in my home directory. When I run `git status`, Git finds directories that don't exist on my machine:

```
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Application Data/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/ElevatedDiagnostics/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/History/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/Content.IE5/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/Low/Content.IE5/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Temporary Internet Files/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Application Data/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Documents/My Music/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Documents/My Pictures/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Documents/My Videos/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Local Settings/': Permission denied
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

Many of the directories above do not exist.  Why is Git trying to open these ***nonexistent*** directories?

My .gitignore:

```
#===============================================================================
# Blacklist everything, then whitelist sub-directories
#===============================================================================
# this allows me to whitelist individual FILES in sub-directories
*
!*/


#===============================================================================
# WHITELIST SPECIFIC THINGS
#===============================================================================
!.gitignore
!.bashrc
!.alias.sh
!.update.home.sh
!.startup.sh
!.todo
!dictionary.txt
!./.config/git/gitk
!Documents/ShareX/ApplicationConfig.json
```

Comment: Are you sure they don’t exist? Those seem like pretty standard things to have in a Window user directory. Try `ls -ld AppData 'Application Data' Documents 'Local Settings'`. Also, making your home directory a repository seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Oh, if you mean specific subdirectories don’t exist – they could be merged from `Default User`. I don’t remember exactly how that works. Would still recommend not doing this. (You can make a script *copy* all the files you want into a repo instead.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again.

from [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) documentation.

So if i get this correctly your line `!*/` (second line in your blacklist area) re-includes all directories in your home directory, apparently including all those above.

To show everything (also the *hidden* directories) in your home directory open the command prompt `"Win" + "R"`, type `cmd` and hit `"Enter"`. Enter
`dir /a`, hit `"Enter"` and you will see that all the directories you were wondering about *do* show up in your home directory.

Comment: I understand that the `!*/` line includes all the directories.
My question is: why is git searching through __nonexistent__ directories?

Comment: They *do* exist. I edited my answer on how you can see that.

Comment: Ahhhh, I get it now.  Thanks for explaining that!